# viewflow: How can I disable long embeded list of data on default frontend screens?

Tags: django-viewflow, viewflow

I'm currently using viewflow frontend for the management part of our workflow and we're getting huge loading times on default views that have started to show just after we started using the system for testing purposes.

Is there a param somewhere I can set so that it doesn't fetch everything?

Here's a picture of what get's rendered in these screens:
[Side cards showing all of db's data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTNR3.png)
[Current process's task view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OvaO.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can override `viewflow/process_data.html` or `[app_name]/[flow_name]/process_data.html` for the specific flow, ex - https://github.com/viewflow/viewflow/blob/master/demo/shipment/templates/shipment/shipment/process_data.html